# How do I properly deal with console_scripts in a docker build

Tags: python, pip, pyinvoke

I have an entrypoint in my setup.cfg:

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    mycmd = my_proj.main:program.run
```

main.py

```
from invoke import Collection, Program
from my_proj import jobs
program = Program(namespace=Collection.from_module(jobs), version="1.2.3")
```

This is my project structure:

```
my_proj
    main.py
    jobs/
        myjob.py
    log_conf
        logger.ini
        logsetup.py
```

If I follow best practices in my Dockerfile it does not work:

```
RUN pip install wheel
COPY setup.cfg setup.py pyproject.toml MANIFEST.in ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache \
    pip install '.'

COPY ./my_proj ./my_proj
```

If I run mycmd in the container I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mycmd", line 5, in <module>
    from my_proj.main import program
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_proj'
```

I also tried just copying the entrypoint: `COPY my_proj/main.py ./my_proj/main.py`

But then I get `pip install ImportError: cannot import name 'jobs' from 'myjob' (unknown location)`

The only solution was to `COPY ./my_proj ./my_proj` *before* running install which stinks because now I need to pip install *every* time I rebuild.

I'm not sure if this is a pyinvoke issue or a pip issue, how do I avoid having to copy my entire project into the image before running `pip install`?

Comment: Try to move COPY line before your line Run...pip install

Comment: I know that works, I said that right in the question, that's what I want to avoid.